# Is adding heat to a system always accompanied by work?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

Whenever we add heat to the system, the KE of the particles increase and so does their momentum.

Thus every time we heat an object by any means, we change the momentum of the particles or in other words, we do work on them.

Is this statement always correct or are there some exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question because it depends on a few different things. As you've probably realized, it depends partly on what we consider the system and what you actually mean by heat, but it mostly comes down to the definition of work.

In the standard cylinder-and-piston example, what do we consider work? The force times displacement of the piston, which we connect to pressure if the piston moves. When we heat the system, ultimately molecules are being excited, which would seem to be work. However, if the system undergoes an isovolumetric process, by heating it while holding the piston in place, we don't have any work, by definition.

Now consider the same case of isovolumetric heating but where work is defined as forcing the molecules around instead of the piston. Now heating up the system does result in work, as we can see in the fact that the system's energy increased through the kinetic energy of the molecules. Now the case you're looking for is where the kinetic energy of the particles is the same even though heat is applied. Since kinetic energy is directly linked to temperature (we're just assuming simple gas behavior), we're looking for an isothermal (constant temperature) process, which involves letting the piston out while adding heat.

The former work definition is just generally more useful since we can push cars and generate electricity with a pulling macroscopic piston.

In case you think I'm skirting the problem, we play with this sort of arbitrary definition of energy types all the time. In simple kinematics, we break energy into kinetic and potential parts. In the cylinder, we make the somewhat arbitrary decision to call molecular kinetic energy transfer heat (though it's actually a form of work) and macroscopic piston movement work. If the molecules have chemical (potential) energy stored up, adding more molecules increases the energy. We also conveniently ignore the fact that molecules can gain or lose gravitational potential energy by changing their height in the cylinder. The reason we ignore these latter two energy transfer mechanisms is because chemical energy doesn't matter unless there's a reaction (so we would need it if we're considering combustion). And gravitational potential energy changes are so small in the cylinder that they're easily surpassed by energy transfer in random thermal molecular bouncing.

While in the cylinder-and-piston example, the distinction between heat and work can be made quite clear, it's not as clear in a biomolecular system. Heat transfer is part of the Brownian motion that moves molecular chains (the system in this case) around, so the heat transfer does cause work (chain movement), no matter how you look at it.

In essence, you must define your system well and define what work means in your context, but yes, you're right that heat transfer is a form of "work". Energy transfer is probably just a better name to call it in your case though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do work without adding heat, in principle (in practice, there's always at least a little friction).

Examples of doing work without adding heat:

1. lift the system against the force of gravity,
2. move a charged system against the force of an electric field,
3. accelerate a system in a frictionless environment, and
4. have the system undergo an adiabatic process.

Note that in the last case the system does heat up, but no heat is added or subtracted and, thus, in principle it is possible to reverse the adiabatic process and get out all of the work that was put in.

Going in the other direction, it is very much possible to heat a system without doing work on it. Consider a sealed sphere of gas, and we put it in contact with a reservoir at higher temperature than the sphere. Assuming the sphere doesn't change volume, no work will be done, but heat will be transferred.

I think that the source of the confusion is that in thermodynamics/statistical mechanics there is a separation between transferals of energy on the microscopic scale that are incoherent/random (heat) and macroscopic scale or coherent/non-random (work). Both work and heat transfers are energy flows, it's just that one is predictable and always reversible (work) and the other is only partially reversible (heat), usually with the application of more work.

Comment: Thank you. But my question was that - Can we add heat to a system without doing work rather than Can we do work without adding heat!

Comment: I just noticed that. I added an example of the converse case.

Comment: But when you place it in a reservoir of higher temperature then the molecules of the sphere would gain KE and momentum. Thus there must be some work done on the molecules and thus on the sphere too !?

Comment: Added a paragraph to address that - there is an important difference between the predictability/controlability of the processes. Because the process of heating the sphere is microscopic and random there is no way for us macroscopic fat-thumbed beings to make the process run backward without consuming more energy because the entropy has gone up.

Comment: Can you please explain the 'separation' between the micro and the macro so that such a confusion won't occur in future?

Comment: I'm not sure - that separation is, honestly a little fuzzy to me. You'll want to look into thought experiments involving Maxwell's Demon to help sort this out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Can we add heat to a system without doing work ?

Yes ,we can .
Take for example the isochoric process in which volume of the gas is constant which means no work done on the or by the gas ,but still we can add heat to the system during the process.

Ofcourse when we heat the gas ,the speed of the molecules increases ,that does not mean we have done work on the gas(atleast not in the thermodynamics language) .Speeds can be  increased by  just heating the gas,no need to do work on the gas .
By work ,in  thermodynamics simply we mean  pushing the PISTON ,when we push the piston ,we do work on the gas ,and then speeds of molecules increase .But simply by heating also we can increase the speeds of the molecules.